# Jersey-Server response failed to send byte []

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, socketexception

I want to send `byte[]` to Jersey Client. Here is my approach.

```
@POST
@Path("/userinfo/")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM })
public Response getResponse(String userID) {

    byte[] val=null;
    Response rezponse=null;
    try {
      val=getResponse(userID);//this returns a valid byte []         
        System.out.println("arry len : "+val.length);        
      rezponse=Response.ok(val).build();
      System.out.println("before response is null : "+(rezponse==null));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return rezponse;
}
```

The system out in the last line of try block states the `rezponse` object is not null and the returning byte array is having data. How ever, this throws exception as following.

```
 SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:574)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:381)
...
```

Here is my Client request.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(SERVER_URL);// String:SERVER_URL referes to the path
WebTarget getDomainPath = target.path("userinfo");
Builder getBuilder=getDomainPath.request();
Response response = getBuilder.post(Entity.entity("USER_005",MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
byte[] ins = (byte[]) response.getEntity();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your client closed the socket before actually reading the response from the server

Comment: Thanks.. Then how can I solve this? What should I do in client side? How ever I could send outputstream instead of byte[]. then no issue.

Comment: It appears that the error is in your Jersey Client. Perhaps you could post that code...